# Здравствуйте! У меня не запускается сайт на локальном сервере и выдает такую ошибку:

Tags: php

Произошла ошибка PHP
Уровень серьезности: 8192

Сообщение: Без скобок `a? до н.э ? d: e` устарел. Используйте либо `(a? B: c)? d: e` или `a? b: (c? d: e)`

Имя файла: helpers / url_helper.php

Номер строки: 162

Обратная трассировка:

Файл: D: \ xampp \ htdocs \ nurbek_isagaliev.kz \ application \ controllers \ Pagea.php
Строка: 6
Функция: helper

Файл: D: \ xampp \ htdocs \ nurbek_isagaliev.kz \ index.php
Строка: 292
Функция: require_once

Comment: Сообщение даже на русском написано. Что конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Это "русский" - автоперевод браузера, только портит, если чесно. Советую отключать при отображении ошибок

Comment: И где мне исправлять теперь ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

**Вложенные тернарные операторы без явного указания скобок**
Во вложенных тернарных операциях должны явно использоваться круглые скобки, чтобы определить порядок операций. Раньше, если скобки явно не заданы, в большинстве случаев левая ассоциативность приводила к неожидаемому поведению.

```
<?php
1 ? 2 : 3 ? 4 : 5;   // устарело
(1 ? 2 : 3) ? 4 : 5; // хорошо
1 ? 2 : (3 ? 4 : 5); // хорошо
?>
```

Источник: [Миграция с PHP 7.3.x на PHP 7.4.x, php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration74.deprecated.php)

Comment: И где мне исправить ошибку?

Comment: Ну явно же указано: "Имя файла: helpers/url_helper.php, Номер строки: 162"

Comment: <?php

class Pagea extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper('url');
 }

 public function index() {
  $data['current'] = 'pagea';
  $data['title'] = 'Title A';

  $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('pages/pagea');
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
 }
}
?>  где ошибка?

Comment: Это же файл контроллера. А нужно открыть файл хелпера и проскролить до 162 строки